# What type of property for subsemigroups or submonoids is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Consider the set on nonzero-rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^*= \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$ as a subsemigroup of the nonzero real numbers $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}-\{0\},$ where the semi-group operation $\cdot$ is multiplication. As a subsemigroup, $\mathbb{Q}^*$ has the additional property that:

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^* \forall y\in \mathbb{Q}^*(x\cdot y\in \mathbb{Q}^*\Rightarrow x\in \mathbb{Q}^*). \tag{1}$$

Can you give me the name for subsemigroups obeying property (1) please? Also, consider the same question, but for monoids, not semigroups. What is the property in that case?

(*edit*: previously I had asked a similar question, replacing “semigroup” with “group”. The answer in that case is all subgroups obey property (1).)

Comment: Your example isn't great, as both $\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ are groups. Maybe a better example would be the even natural numbers $2\mathbb{N}$, as a subsemigroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition?

Comment: @user1729: That doesn't have the property: $(-4) + 8 = 4\in 2\mathbb{N}$, with $8\in 2\mathbb{N}$, but $-4\notin 2\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If the answer to your previous question was satisfactory, then please accept an answer so that it signals to readers that you are done with it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops! That should have been "...as a subsemigroup of $\mathbb{N}$ under addition".

Comment: @user1729: Okay,, that makes sense. On the other hand, it amounts to a "subgroup example in disguise", since it the result of taking $2\mathbb{Z}\leq\mathbb{Z}$ and intersecting them with the semigroup $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, but I am afraid most semigroups I am friendly with embed into groups! (When I read the question I kept thinking "but these are groups!", which was distracting. I thought having a concrete non-group example, however contrived, was therefore helpful as it means the question is meaningful.)

Comment: @user1729: That much I agree with; it would be better to have a nontrivial example that doesn't derive from groups, or doesn't embed into groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Another, less group-like, class of examples are semigroups $S$ which are the disjoint union of a subsemigroup $T$ and an ideal $I$, so $S=T\sqcup I$; here $T$ has the required property. For example, in $\{0, 1\}$ under multiplication we can take $T=\{1\}$ and $I=\{0\}$. (I think this is ring-like, which my local semigroup theorist claims is the "correct" setting for semigroups: if $R$ is a ring, $I$ an ideal closed under multiplication, and $R/I$ has no zero divisors then take the multiplicative structure on $R$ for your semigroup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset $P$ of a semigroup is *right unitary* if for all $p \in P$ and $s \in S$, $sp \in P$ implies $s \in P$.
It is *left unitary* if for all $p \in P$ and $s \in S$, $ps \in P$ implies $s \in P$. It is *unitary* if it is both left and right unitary. This definition applies of course to subsemigroups.

If you are looking for examples, the class of $E$-unitary semigroups (semigroups in which the set of idempotents form a unitary subsemigroup) has been extensively studied, both in the [regular case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup#E-unitary_inverse_semigroups) and in the general case [1].

EDIT. Another famous example: a submonoid of a free monoid is free if and only if it is unitary.

Also note that there is a similar definition for categories. A subcategory $N$ of a category $C$ is said to be *unitary* if for all $x, y \in {\text Mor}(C)$,

1. if $xy, x \in {\text Mor}(N)$, then $y \in {\text Mor}(N)$ and
2. if $xy, y \in {\text Mor}(N)$, then $xy \in {\text Mor}(N)$.

[1] J. Almeida, J.-É. Pin and P. Weil, [Semigroups whose idempotents form a subsemigroup](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00019881/fr/), *Math. Proc. Cambridge Phil. Soc.* **111** (1992), 241-253.